# How to write a subquery to optimise performance?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have the following query that shows total sales for the selected dimensions. `Table a` does not contain `product_name`, this is why I've joined data with `table b` on `product_id`.

However, `table b` is too big, and I'd like to optimize it to scan fewer data.

```
SELECT a.date,
         a.hour,
         a.category_id,
         a.product_id,
         b.product_name,  
         sum(a.sales) AS sales
FROM  a
LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.product_id = b.product_id
WHERE date(a.date) >= date('2021-01-01') 
      AND date(B.date) = date('2021-01-01')
GROUP BY  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

What would be your suggestions here?

Comment: Firstly I'd suggest qualifying all your columns with the correct alias so we (and you) can clearly see what comes from where. We don't know what existing index you have but indexes on `date` and `product_id` would help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've improved it now. @Stu

Comment: Please provide information on how the tables are partitioned, and what data formats you use. Without this information it's very hard to say anything when it comes to Athena.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to decrease the amount of data Athena needs to scan for a given query:

1. Make sure the table is partitioned, and make sure the query makes use of the partitioning.
2. Store the data as Parquet or ORC.

These two can be used separately or in combination. Best results are achieved with the combination, but sometimes that's not convenient or possible.

Your question doesn't say if the tables are partitioned, but from the query it looks to me like they are not – unless `date` is a partition key.

`date` would be an excellent partition key, and if it is, your query is already pretty good. `AND date(B.date) = date('2021-01-01')` will limit the scan of the table `b` to a single partition. However, if `date` is not a partition key then what will happen is that Athena will have to scan the whole table to find rows that match the criteria.

This is where a file format like Parquet and ORC can help; these store the data for each column separately, and also store metadata like the min and max values for each column. If the files for the `b` table were sorted by `date`, or at least created over time in such a way that they were mostly sorted by `date`, Athena would be able to look at the metadata and skip files that can't contain the sought date because it's outside of the range given by the min/max values for that file. Athena would also only have to read the parts of the files for the `b` table that contained the `date` column, because that is the only one used in the query.

If you amend your question with a little more information about the table schemas and how the data is stored I can answer in more detail how to optimise. With the available information I can only give general guidance as above.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure b table has indexes on date and product_id, as Stu's comment suggests
2. Run an Explain Plan (from console) on your SQL to see whether optimizer filters b before joining to a.  If it already does so, you're done - step 3 won't help
3. Replace your `From a Left Join b` with `From a Left Join (Select product_id, product_name from b where date(date) = date('2021-01-01')) b`

Comment: Please note that Athena does not supporting indexing, so 1 does not apply. The only thing that can help the query not read the full table is if `date` is a partition key, so 2 & 3 also don't apply to Athena.